# Countable subadditivity of seminorm in $c_{00}$:

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functional-analysis

Consider the subspace [$\mathbb{K}=\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{K} =\mathbb{C}$]
$$c_{00} := \left\lbrace x=\left (\xi _j\right )_{j=1}^\infty |\xi _j\in\mathbb{K}, \exists N\in\mathbb{N} : j >N\Longrightarrow\xi _j = 0 \right\rbrace $$
equipped with the norm $\|x\|_\infty = \max\limits_{1\leq j\leq N}|\xi _j|$.

Let's also look at a seminorm $p =\|\cdot\|_1$ on $c_{00}: p(x) = \|x\|_1 =\sum_{k=1}^\infty|\xi _j|$

> $p$ is said to be countably subadditive if for every $x = \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k$ [convergent series of sequences] we have that $p(x)\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty p(x_k)$

Show that $p$ is countably subadditive in $c_{00}$.
**Attempt:**
Let $\sum_{j=1}^\infty x_j$ be an arbitrary convergent series in $c_{00}$. Must show that:
$$p\left (\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k\right )\leq \sum_{k=1}^\infty p(x_k)\Longleftrightarrow \left\lvert\left\lvert \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k\right\rvert\right\rvert_1\leq\sum_{k=1}^\infty\|x_k\|_1 $$

We have for some $n\in\mathbb{N}$
$$\left\lvert\left\lvert \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k\right\rvert\right\rvert_1 = \|x\|_1 =\sum_{k=1}^n |\xi _k|\leq n\|x\|_\infty $$
therefore, if $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \|x\|_1$ diverges, the inequality holds trivially.
**Problem** What do we do when said series converges?

We can't invoke continuity of $p$ to pass triangle ineq. to the limit, because there is no continuity:
Assume, there exists $K\geq 0$, such that
$$p(x)\leq K\|x\|_\infty\ \forall x\in c_{00} $$
So, naturally, consider $y = (K, K, \ldots, K, 0, 0,\ldots)\in c_{00}$, where $K$ appears $m$ times. For sufficiently large $m$
$$p(y) = \sum_{k=1}^m K = mK > K^2 = K\|y\|_\infty $$
therefore, $p$ is not bounded and equivalently, not continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write $x_k = (x_{k1}, x_{k2}, \cdots, )$. Then

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty \|x_k\|_1 = \sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty |x_{kj}|.$$

If this is finite, we can switch the order of summation

$$\sum_{k=1}^\infty\sum_{j=1}^\infty |x_{kj}| = \sum_{j=1}^\infty\sum_{k=1}^\infty |x_{kj}|\ge \sum_{j=1}^\infty\left| \sum_{k=1}^\infty x_{kj}\right|= \sum_{j=1}^\infty |x^j|,$$

where $x =(x^1, x^2,\cdots)$. The last equality comes from the definition $x = \sum {x_k}$.

Comment: Forgot about the order of summation trick. Thanks!